# How to find a curve that fits a series of points on the R?

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I need to find out the equation of the power curve that adjusts to the contaminated per day of a certain disease so that I can make a prediction, the data follows:

```
Day     Contaminated

26/feb  1
29/feb  2
04/mar  3
05/mar  8
06/mar  13
07/mar  19
08/mar  25
10/mar  34
11/mar  52
12/mar  81
13/mar  98
14/mar  121
15/mar  176
16/mar  234
17/mar  291
18/mar  428
19/mar  621
20/mar  904
21/mar  1128
22/mar  1546
23/mar  1891
24/mar  2201
25/mar  2433
```

I believe that I need to do a power curve regression(NonLinearRegression) in R, but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: It can be hard to show that you have done sufficient research, but I do not see enough to suggest you did any before coming here to SO. On google, I include `"r"` and/or `"CRAN"` (quotes intentional) in my searches; I occasionally use https://rseek.org; on SO, one *must* use include `[r]` to search only within the [tag:r] tag (other tags can be useful). The important point is that we absolutely want you to do your homework before coming here. Understand that our time is not free, though we do not charge for it. Answering low quality, poorly researched, or dupe questions becomes tiresome.

Comment: I understand completely, it may not seem like it, but I researched about it all day. I'm from the Portuguese forum, I searched it all over and found nothing on how to do this type of regression. I really need help, sorry if it looks like something else.

Comment: To be clear, this is a generic question about advanced statistics; it is not about programming (other than "how to program this regression"), and it is not a question about a specific model you have built (should migrate to [stats.se]). I don't know of any StackExchange sites that are intended to be used as complete *tutorials* or *lesson plans*, and SO is no exception. While many answers do have sufficient detail to be useful as a mini-howto or such, I believe that that is the exception. And asking for that much is off-topic, please see [help/on-topic].

Comment: What methodology do you have in mind exactly? R would be just a way to implement it. Here you are sure to find help about R specific or if you want to learn more about R. So I afraid you might not be in the right place if you want to know more. I would suggest. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_diffusion_model][this] or this [https://homes.stat.unipd.it/renatoguseo/content/ricerca](this).  Do go too fast the road might be long ;-)

Comment: Thanks DJJ for the articles, I will search further. I had in mind to use a nonlinear regression in R, more precisely the power curve regression. I viewed countless articles on non-linear regression in R, Curve Fitting and Power Curve but I was unable to implement it in R with my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using `data.table`, `ggplot2` and `nls`.

First, let's fix the dates into the standard format and convert to integers so we can do some calculations.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
setDT(data)
data[,Day:= as.Date(Day,"%d/%b")]
data[,Int := as.integer(Day)-min(as.integer(Day))]
```

Then we use `nls` to fit a model to the data. We'll use the formula `y = a * x ^ b`.

```
nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data,start=list(a=1,b=1))
# Nonlinear regression model
#  model: Contaminated ~ a * Int^b
#   data: data
#        a         b 
#2.272e-05 5.571e+00 
# residual sum-of-squares: 123279
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 48 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.832e-07
```

Now we can view the results with `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Int,y=Contaminated)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,10,20), labels = data$Day[data$Int %in% c(0,10,20)]) + xlab("Date") +
  geom_smooth(method="nls", formula = y ~ a * x ^ b,method.args = list(start = c(a=1, b=1)),se=FALSE, linetype = 1)
```

[image]
**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Day = c("26/feb", "29/feb", "04/mar", "05/mar", 
"06/mar", "07/mar", "08/mar", "10/mar", "11/mar", "12/mar", "13/mar", 
"14/mar", "15/mar", "16/mar", "17/mar", "18/mar", "19/mar", "20/mar", 
"21/mar", "22/mar", "23/mar", "24/mar", "25/mar"), Contaminated = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 19L, 25L, 34L, 52L, 81L, 98L, 121L, 176L, 234L, 
291L, 428L, 621L, 904L, 1128L, 1546L, 1891L, 2201L, 2433L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the help, really! But I'm not getting the code to my R at all. By passing "nls (formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data, start = list (a = 1, b = 1))" I get the error that iterations have exceeded the maximum of 50.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same `data` that I provided at the end of the answer. Also, you could try `stats::nls(formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data,start=list(a=1,b=1))`.

Comment: I used the data provided and also the formula provided in the comment, but the error continues

Comment: Hi @Magliari, just to be sure it was working, I logged into my hospital's linux cluster and ran the code there. As you can see, [it works](https://i.imgur.com/P98TqgM.png). I would recommend executing the lines of code you see with `>` or `+` in front of them slowly and sequentially.

Comment: Thank you very much for sending the print of your code. I copied it correctly to my R, but the error persists. Cotinua speaking, the number of iterations exceeded the maximum of 50. I transferred his code to my R countless times. My Code:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/hZgsHBO) . Sorry for the inconvenience, but I'm very interested.

Comment: What if you try the code on [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/)? [You can see here that it works](https://i.imgur.com/i7ZkjGm.png). Could it be that you have `a` and/or `b` assigned? You could try `rm(list=c("a","b"))`.

Comment: @Maglan, I ran the code in the answer and was able to reproduce the output in the answer.  Suggest you try again with a fresh R session with nothing loaded initially.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, really. When trying to update the data and run on the console, I get this error `Error in nls (formula = Contaminated ~ a * Int ^ b, data, start = list (a = 1,:
   step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
Execution halted`
[Link](https://imgur.com/a/4iHghrw) @Ian Campbell